# Decrement row ID and Input ID after deleting dynamically added rows javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create a table with some text input. The user have the possibility to add another row to the table. I found many example on web to create add and remove function.

I have to increment the id of row and the input.

The problem is when i delete the row the id of this row and input remain the same but i have to decremented the id.

Someone could help me please with some example?

Comment: It might be best to *not* decrement the ID on deletion -- in general it's best not to recycle used IDs, because it creates the potential for accidental conflicts...  but it really depends on what you're using them for (will they be stored permanently with the user input? Or are they just for the input form itself? What's the reason you want them to be sequential even after deletions?)  An example of what you're trying to do might help get you better answers; as is there's not really enough detail here for people to be able to understand what you need.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This is similar: https://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

Comment: But i have to rearrange the id when you remove a field